# Does the "/MT" switch remove the need for vc runtime?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, dll, dependencies, vcredist

I am compiling my VS 2012 DLL with the /MT switch.

Does that mean that I won't have to redistribute the VC runtimes (vcredist)?

I am asking because my DLL cannot be registered on a clean XP SP3 client computer. If I distribute the VC 2012 runtime, it works.

I thought that the /MT switch would remove the need for it. 
Did I misunderstand that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/MT` should link your code against the static runtime.  However that doesn't necessarily mean that you are not linked against other libraries that required the dynamic runtime.  You can use `dumpbin /imports` to see if it is actually required to run your program. I haven't really worked with Visual Studio since 2010 but [dumpbin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1h23y6c.aspx) should still be supplied somewhere.

Comment: Dumpbin tells me that my DLL uses the following imports: Kernel32.dll, user32.dll, advapi32.dll, shell32.dll, ole32.dll, oleaut32.dll. Does that mean that it should theoretically work with deploying the vcredist?

Comment: There is still the possibility that you are referencing a symbol that doesn't exist in one of the shared libraries on XP.  If it isn't working then there is probably something missing.  TBH, the best way to get to the bottom quickly is to run a dependency walker on the XP box.  Look for a copy of `depends.exe`.  It will load your DLL and highlight any missing symbols.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. But could you please confirm that I should theoretically not need the vcredist anymore if my DLL does NOT reference any other symbols than the ones I mentioned? You said it "links your code against the static runtime". So is the VC2012-runtime then compiled into my DLL?